# The bad old Noise issue in the headphones on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have migrated to Ubuntu from Windows recently. It has been a great experience. But, one thing annoyed me the most and that is the headphones noise issue. It is a very common problem and I have almost gone through every question asked about this issue on the forum. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my *DELL INSPIRON 15 3542 touchscreen* laptop.

I have tried :

- `alsamixer` and disabling the Loopback Mixing
- Adding 0 in the `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` file
- INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
  in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave`

Nothing worked, not even temporarily.

---

Now, what I have observed is whenever I open the **PulseAudio Volume Controller** and keep it open, the noise is gone! As soon as the application is closed, the noise comes back. So, this seems to work temporarily and a cheap solution. Can anyone look into this matter and come up with a permanent solution for the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of users are facing noise problem when headphones are connected and are fed up with it just like I am. This solution is for them. There are a lot of solutions given on askubuntu but none have worked for me.

Things were good when I used Windows 8.1. There was no such sound issue. Well, but now I am on Ubuntu and I have no plans of going back to Windows.

I have accepted the fact that my laptop's sound system is not shielded properly.
I haven't addressed the root of the problem, but just kind of made it a virtually unnoticable.

So, the hack is quite simple. As the problem persists only when there is no playback, I came up with a hack to always have a playback!
Now, this should be true only when the headphones are connected. And the playback should stop when headphones are removed.

Follow these simple steps-

**Step #1:** Install mplayer and configure it.

```
sudo apt install mplayer    
nano ~/.mplayer/config
```

type in that file-> `lirc=no`

**Step #2:** Download this mp3 file from [here](http://www.jetcityorange.com/silent-ringtone/silence-10sec.mp3) (silence-10sec.mp3)

**Step #3:** Create a folder in home directory and name it `.hush`
Copy the mp3 file in your `.hush` directory

```
cp ~/Downloads/silence-10sec.mp3 ~/.hush/
```

In that folder, create a script file and name it `silence.sh`
Copy paste this code in the script file.

```
#!/bin/bash

plugged="jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug"
unplugged="jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug"

acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r event;
do
    if [ "$event" == "$plugged" ]
    then
       mplayer -really-quiet -loop 0 ~/.scripts/silence-10sec.mp3 &
    elif [ "$event" == "$unplugged" ]
    then
       pkill -f mplayer
    fi
done
```

Make it executable with the command `chmod +755 silence.sh`

**Step #4:** Type `startup applications` in the Dash and add the path of silence.sh script to it.

[image]

So, basically what we are doing is listening to events of headphones been connected and disconnected and playing or stopping the blank mp3 file in a loop. Now, I have used `mplayer` because I know that I am never gonna use that for any other purpose and killing its process is completely safe for me.

I came  up with this idea when [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg) answered to one of my [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879139/using-acpi-listen-command-in-a-shell-script).
He came up with this script and I just made modifications to it to suite the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I like and had to use this approach as I couldn't correct the problem even with [these root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632306/hissing-noise-over-headphones-only-in-ubuntu) changes made to terminate the power save of the headphones. One change I made though was to install the sox pagae to use the play feature and also mp3 support:

`$ sudo apt install sox` # contains 'play' to play audio
`$ sudo apt install libsox-fmt-all` # to enable mp3 support

```
#!/bin/bash

plugged="jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug"
unplugged="jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug"

acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r event;
do
    if [ "$event" == "$plugged" ]
    then
       play -loop 0 /home/$USER/.hush/10-seconds-of-silence.mp3 &
    elif [ "$event" == "$unplugged" ]
    then
       pkill -f play
    fi
done
```

Note try opening the following and changing 1 to 0:

```
$ sudo nano cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

This did work for me but had trouble even as root overwriting the file likely as it is being updated as it's being used (not 100% on that) I brute forced it and once replaced, headphones became silent.