# Audio Issues - How to Troubleshoot? (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: sound

Since installing Ubuntu about two weeks ago my audio has been giving me problems. Anything that is connected to the audio jack on the back of my computer ends up coming out as a loud static mess. I don't have this issue with headphones or speakers connected to the front audio jack. Audio sounds fine under Windows 10. What can I do to pinpoint where the issue lies?

Edit: Motherboard is an ASRock Taichi x370 if that helps any.

Comment: What's the manufacturer / model of the computer or motherboard ? You may need to disable audio power saving: [Hissing noise over headphones only in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632306/hissing-noise-over-headphones-only-in-ubuntu).

Comment: The motherboard is an ASRock Taichi x370